# Go to the anchor link after window.location.reload

Tags: javascript, anchor

I'm trying to update hash and then reload page.

```
$('a[name="' + fragment + '"]').remove(); //don't jump before window reloads
window.location.hash = fragment;
window.location.reload(true);
```

After reload window doesn't jump to anchor tag. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why would you use the hash, and then reload the page ?

Comment: I **think** you are better of by changing the `href` property: `window.location.href = url + '#your-hash';`

Comment: The idea is to reload the page and then jump screen to specific place on the page

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly trivial to achieve in jQuery if you are reloading the page. Just check the `window.location.hash` property when loading the page.

```
$(document).ready( function( ) {
    if( window.location.hash ) { // just in case there is no hash
        $(document.body).animate({
            'scrollTop':   $( window.location.hash ).offset().top
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

The only caveat is that your hash matches the id of the element you are scrolling to.

Demo [**here**](http://jsbin.com/iretij/2#bar)

Answer (score 1):

[MOZILLA DEVELOPER NETWORK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) suggest using `replace`:

```
function reloadPageWithHash() {
  var initialPage = window.location.pathname;
  window.location.replace('http://example.com/#' + initialPage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tim S. my intention is absolutely not to steal your thunder but your very low key comment above is in my opinion the optimal solution to this question as it is simple, clean and tests successfully across a variety of browsers. I am therefore creating an answer of it on your behalf:

```
window.location.href = url#anchor
```

(where url can be the current page - or a different one as desired)

Comment: this DOES NOT reload the page if url / anchor is the same.